# PiHole not blocking advertisements

Tags: raspbian, pi-zero-w, pi-hole

I installed and updated Raspbian OS and PiHole on a **Raspberry Pi Zero W**. But the adblocking feature is not working.

I am attempting to make RPi as DNS for my modem over ethernet. I have assigned fixed IP addresses to **wlan0** and **eth0** interfaces of RPi among along with other devices in admin console of my modem:

[image: LAN Reservation in modem]

I am attempting to make RPi as DNS for my modem over ethernet.

[image: DNS Setup]

The same IP addresses can be seen the RPi in the tooltip from network icon:

[image: IP addresses seen in tooptip]

The output of the terminal commands `nslook pi.hole` and `pihole status` are in the screenshot below:

[image]

The IP address for *Server* looks strange, perhaps because `server can't find pi.hole: NXDOMAIN`.

Looking at the log of PiHole, it is detecting traffic from only itself (localhost) and from Kumar's Echo.

[image: PiHole Log]

Here's the screenshot from *Settings* menu > *System* tab:

[image: Settings > System]

And here is screenshot  from *Settings* menu > *DHCP* tab:

[image: Settings > DHCP]

I have uninstalled, reinstalled; and performed `pihole reconfigure` and `pihole restartdns` several times. As suggested in another similar question, I restarted my modem after installing PiHole several times.

Any solution please?

*Please note that I am not a pro or an advanced user of Linux.* :)

Comment: the output of nslookup is telling you that your DNS server is 8.26.56.26 - so, not your pihole

Comment: you need to maybe restart your router once so all connections are terminated and your router notified your devices of new DNS server. Look for DNS server after that.

Comment: @Jaromanda X - I can see that but don't know why.

Comment: @Bijay Regmi - As I said in my question, I restarted modem several times after reinstalling / reconfiguring PiHole. And even 10 minutes back.

Comment: how does the computer in that picture get its DNS address? It doesn't use DHCP, since it IS the DHCP server, so where is it getting its DNS address from? Oh, wait ... is the Pi your DHCP server, or is it still the main gateway that is your DHCP server?

Comment: If I am correct, my modem is the DHCP server as well as the main gateway; and RPi is supposed to be the DNS server.